# How to dynamically add images from server to a linear layout

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, imageview, android-linearlayout

Hi i am trying to load images from server and add them dynamically into a linearlayout which is inside a scroll view

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<RssItem> result) {
    Log.i("Async-Example", "onPostExecute Called");
    horview = (HorizontalScrollView) aview.findViewById(R.id.homesection);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) aview.findViewById(R.id.sectionid);
    for(int i = 0; i < rssItems.size(); i++){
        try{
        image = new ImageView(getActivity());
        image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //text.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
        aview.setTag(rssItems.get(i).getLink());
        image.setFocusable(true);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(rssItems.get(i).getLink(), image);
        ll.addView(image);  

    }catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is: if I am declaring ImageView inside my LinearLayout in xml, then only the last image from the server is added. But if i don't declare the `ImageView` inside linear layout and instead instantiate and add to it, none of the images from the server replace my actual default icon

Comment: What's this `imageLoader.DispayImage`? Add a log statement in the `catch`-clause, are there any exceptions?

Comment: you have to add finally your linear layout to ScrollView..

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the ImageView with XML inside the LinearLayout, as this will only result in a single view being inflated. Initiating ImageViews on the go as you do should work, but to me it sounds like you are trying to load a list of images fetched from a website, in which case you would normally use a ListView with a custom adapter. There are a lot of tutorials online for this:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

I think the problem in your code is related to the imageLoader. If you are having problems it, you can always try another one like http://square.github.io/picasso/ and call

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(rssItems.get(i).getLink()).into(image);
```

Comment: i am using a horizontal scrollview and inside that i am adding linearlayout and in linear layout i am adding imageview,how to achieve the same using view pager?

Comment: How to use a ViewPager is not relevant to the original question, and you should ask this in a new question if you need help with it. However, simply searching for tutorials on google will get you far: [Android ViewPager Gallery Images and Texts Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/)